# Rails/React: storing "Todo" items within React state?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

So im working on a React "Todo" list as a first React project, im using Rails as an API backend (strictly taking in and sending back .json), I am fairly familiar with Rails or at least the basics.

Currently I have a few Components for handling the actual "List". This being a ListContainer parent component (Holds the state for "Lists" which is an array of Lists) as well as all the Add/Update/Delete/Index(Set Lists initial state) functions.

Along with some child components (ListForm and List), both pretty self explanatory. List being a dumb component just holding the List title and description, and ListForm being the actual form to submit a new list.

I am using axios, and so far Create/Index/Update/Delete are working great for Lists. However I am running into the issue of being unsure how to handle the list items themselves. Currently in the rails side Lists `has_many` list_items and list_items `belong_to`list`.

So rails has the relationship side all buttoned up...but im really unsure how to handle the actual items on the javascript side (for each list).

My first initial guess was to switch "List" dumb component to a smart component that handles state, in this state would be an array of "list_items" that belong to that particular list. When the List is loaded I imagine axios performing a GET request for that lists items within the  component. And then basically handling add/delete/update similar to how the ListContainer component handles it for Lists (but instead making "List" component the de-facto container component for ListItems (which is currently a "dumb component")

Does this make sense? I honestly am still pretty new to react so handling relationships on the front end side is something im not familiar with yet. But storing state within a child that "belongs_to" a parent state/component makes the most sense initially? Unless I am overthinking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proposed solution makes sense. Following your pattern you would probably have another Component, ListItem, and you would map through the listItems state in List and display a ListItem for each item.

That being said, many people learning react have a tendency to over-complicate it by having too many components/different files interacting. At one time the React community encouraged this, but they have since backed off on doing so. Many people now consider having presentational components (or "dumb" components, as you call them) an antipattern. See, for example, this note from Dan Abramov [enter link description here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)